# Unable to set MAXDOP option on a non-clustered columnstore Index

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-2019, non-clustered-index, columnstore

I'm trying to set `MAXDOP` option on a non-clustered columnstore index using the following ways and it doesn't seem to be sticking. Server is  SQL Server 2019.

1. Index properties -> Options Page -> Maximum Degree of Parallelism. I have set this to 2 and hit OK. It doesn't show me any error but when I check the index properties again, it shows 0 for Maximum Degree of Parallelism.
2. `ALTER INDEX IXCS_Test ON [DBTest].[TBLTest] REBUILD WITH (MAXDOP = 2)` This statement executes successfully without errors but again, when I check the properties of the index it's still at 0.

After trying each the above options, I tried scripting the index as a Create statement and I don't see the `MAXDOP` option in the script.

What am I missing here? Please help.

Comment: `MAXDOP` is simply not a property of an index. It's an option only on an index *operation*. It isn't stored or persisted anywhere. SSMS is just offering a needlessly confusing  interface here.

Comment: Be interesting to know what SQL it actually runs as a result of doing this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/configure-parallel-index-operations#to-set-max-degree-of-parallelism-on-an-index. Does it do an unadvertised rebuild?

Comment: @MartinSmith: that page is somehow *even worse* at explaining what it does! It fully commits to the fantasy that this is setting an index option somehow. And no, simply changing this value on its own does absolutely nothing (verified empirically). Only if you do something in the properties window that would warrant rebuilding the index does `MAXDOP` do anything, and in that case it adds the option to the statement(s) generated.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, your explanation makes sense. On mobile so was unable to look myself

Comment: This would make for a beautiful "gotcha" question on a job interview for a DBA... if such questions weren't awful, I mean. "If you open this properties window, go to "options" and set this to 4, what happens when you click OK? 1. It rebuilds the index immediately with this option, 2. It sets the option for future rebuilds, but doesn't rebuild immediately, or 3. absolutely bloody nothing since this isn't actually an index property and the people who made the interface couldn't think of a better way to surface this." :P

Comment: Thanks, I created a PR on that doc page: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/7457

Comment: So I have an SSIS package with multiple steps. 2 of the steps involve index rebuilds. My goal is to ensure that it utilizes MAXDOP of 2, whenever this index rebuilds. Based on this conversation, I'm assuming that if I update the alter statements as below in those 2 steps, its all set. Is that correct?

`ALTER INDEX IXCS_Test ON [DBTest].[TBLTest] REBUILD WITH (MAXDOP = 2)`

Comment: As long as you make sure that the option is used on every instance of that statement, then yes. Nothing prevents an `ALTER INDEX` without that option from executing, of course.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert - Thanks for the clarification! Can you post your comments as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution?